# To know the output directory of the module

Tags: python, machine-learning, spacy

I am very new to python programming and spacy module, here i created my own module of Named entity Recognition, It is working fine but i want to know where the Module is saved in the output directory,please help me

## save model to output directory

```
if output_dir is not None:
    output_dir = Path(output_dir)
    if not output_dir.exists():
        output_dir.mkdir()
    nlp.meta['name'] = new_model_name  #rename model
    nlp.to_disk(output_dir)
    print("Saved model to", output_dir)

    # test the saved model
    print("Loading from", output_dir)
    nlp2 = spacy.load(output_dir)
    doc2 = nlp2(test_text)
    for ent in doc2.ents:
        print(ent.label_, ent.text)
```

Comment: The module is saved wherever you saved it. Your question makes no sense. Please try to rephrase it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you want to know to which directory your trained model is saved. You even have the variable `output_dir` in your code. Just look up to what value it is set and go there in your file system. If that is not the problem you are facing, please clarify your question.